# V-Calendar dates not showing the correct dates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vcalendar, v-calendar.io

[image: June 2022]

The dates on the shown image are starting on the 1st of June, 2022 which is supposed to be a Wednesday but on the calendar, it is on Sunday. All months start on a Sunday not only June. I am only using `<v-calendar />` with no extra props or configurations. I am using v2.4.1 of the v-calendar package.

This is how I am importing the package. Also, I am using Nuxt.js. Our other product uses Vue where the calendar is correct.

/plugins/v-calendar.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VCalendar from "v-calendar";

Vue.use(VCalendar, {
  componentPrefix: "v",
});
```

nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [
   { src: "@/plugins/v-calendar.js", ssr: false },
],
```

page.vue

```
<v-calendar />
```

Answer (score 1):

With no plugins set, `v-calendar` start the week by sunday (which is the american convention). If you want to change this, on can use the `firstDayOfWeek` property. (See [documentation here](https://vcalendar.io/i18n.html))

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```css
@import url 'https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@2.4.1/lib/v-calendar.min.css';
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@2.4.1/lib/v-calendar.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <v-calendar :first-day-of-week="2"></v-calendar>
</div>
```

Otherwise, the June month start by default on wednesday using the classic configuration as you can see from the above snippet. The error might come from your configuration

Comment: I had configurations previously but just to check whether its the configurations I removed all of it. Still the problem persists.

Comment: Can you provide a codepen to show your code and configuration ?

Comment: I can only reproduce this on my project. When I try it on codepen this works fine. I have edited the question to have all the code related to v-calendar. Also I am using Nuxt.js if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what issue you are facing, But just to reproduce the issue I created a demo and it is showing proper start date.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    const now = new Date()
    const later = new Date(now.getTime() + 5 * 60 * 1000)
    return {
      value: null,
      availableDates: [
        { start: now, end: later }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@2.4.1"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <v-calendar/>
</div>
```